# Importing only specific files from a svn repository to git

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm trying to import a few files from SVN to a new git repository.

For Example, I have the following in SVN:

```
  files/file1
  files/file2
  files/file3
  files/image1
  files/image2
```

I want to import only the `files/image*` files.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from your tags that you're using git-svn? If so, check out the `--ignore-paths` option. Use it on `git svn init` or `git svn clone` to have the values you pass preserved in the local config, or on `git svn fetch` for per-fetch ignoring.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the --ignore-paths option?  I'm currently on git 1.5.5.6 and it's not available, but looking into having it upgraded.

Comment: Have you tried creating a .gitignore file? Not sure how that'll play with git-svn but worth a try.

Comment: I did try the .gitignore route.  Both in my home directory and in the repo directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link. http://ivanz.com/2009/01/15/selective-import-of-svn-branches-into-a-gitgit-svn-repository/ Hope this helps!

---

1. Define the new branch in .git/config :

   ```
   [svn-remote "release-branch"]
   url = svn+ssh://xxxx@mono-cvs.ximian.com/source/branches/mono-2-2/mcs
   fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn-release-branch
   ```
2. Import the SVN branch. SVN_BRANCHED_REVISION is the the revision when the branch happened in SVN.

   ```
   [~]$ git svn fetch release-branch -r SVN_BRANCHED_REVISION
   ```
3. Hook up a local Git branch to the remote branch:

   ```
   [~]$ git branch --track release git-svn-release-branch
   ```
4. Checkout and update

   ```
   [~]$ git checkout release
   [~]$ git svn rebase
   ```

Done!